# OpenVz and Proxmox run websites and control panel

Tags: virtual-machine, openvz

I create OpenVz containers in NAT , for this for example i create 2 containers and in each container i put 2 control panel ispconfig , all works and for works use forward ip and i can access with the same ip and change the port for example :

Control panel of ispconfig access by this URL :

32.455.32.21:1090

And access theother control panel of ispconfig with this :

32.455.32.21:1125

All ok , and works , the problem it´s for add domains in each case , i try use register A into DNS and put the ip with the port for access the domain and redirect of web content , but into DNS A records no let insert ports , by this i have this question , it´s possible use this control panels and add domains for load the content of websites in each container and using the same ip but change the ports , this it´s the dude i have or finally yes or yes i need buy ipfailover for works with these control panel and add domains , etc .....

Thank´s for the ideas and the help , Regards

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the DNS to point to a port. 
You will have to put some other method in place to do this. Typically you would use a front end webserver (or a dedicated proxy server) to proxy the connection from port 80 to port 100 based on the name of the server being requested.